# Algorithm to evenly distribute "prizes" / no variance lottery

Tags: php, algorithm, graph, distribution

My problem: I want to make a "kind" lottery-process. This algorithm will distribute prizes evenly if possible. This could be considered unfair to the people who buy a ticket to every prize since he will be more flexible to win the unpopular prizes, but never mind that, we may say that the prizes are roughly the same. The algorithm will help killing variance and reduce the dicerolling to win prizes. (Yep, boring)

I will have `N` competitions were you can win a prize. The persons, `M`, can buy a ticket for every `N`.

So an example, here are prizes and people who have bought tickets:

```
Prize1=[Pete,Kim, Jim]
Prize2=[Jim, Kim]
Prize3=[Roger, Kim]
Prize4=[Jim]
```

There are 4 prizes and 4 unique names, so it should be possible to distribute it evenly.

The example may be easy to solve, you should find it out in 15 seconds,  but when `M` and `N` increase it gets much worse.

I'm trying to make a general algorithm, but it's hard. I need some good tips or even better the solution or link to a solution.

Comment: The word you are looking for is 'prize', not 'price', just so you know.  Confused me a bit.

Comment: So how are you supposed to distribute the prizes?

Comment: By assigning the prizes they can win so everyone is assured to win x prizes each- the rest has to be distributed by random lottery.

Answer (score 1):

Theory: You have a [Bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph). You have to find a [Perfect matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_matching). There is a perfect matching in a graph if:

- |A| = |B|
- The graph satisfies the [Hall condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theory)

If a perfect matching exists, you can run the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) to find it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up just brute forcing my way to a sollution. The web server is fast and the m and n are not that large :) The solution is so bad its rediculous, im bombarding it with random numbers until it fit my criteria, guess i program it better when I have time :-)

Comment: FYI: you can't solve this problem with bruteforce if n > ~30.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look for a job-assignment algorithm, or a hungarian algorithm for example a weighted perfect match in a bipartite graph, or maybe the all-pair floyd warshall algorithm. My idea is that this can be represent as a bipartite graph. This is not an easy to solve task.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you, i came up with a brute force sollution which sucked, haha. Efficient CPUs are making us stupid :D